# How to pass two values in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

As currently am passing filtered array list to set adapter for autocomplete text view,in that i need t get the position of the elements ?

Below is the code.
 i have iterated to get the Title,but with that i need URI which is in tabList.from this i need to pass it to ArrayAdapter.So how can i proceed to my requirement.

```
if (tabsList != null) {
            Iterator iterator = tabsList.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Tabs tabs = (Tabs) iterator.next();
                Iterator iterator1 = tabs.getCardInfo().iterator();
                while (iterator1.hasNext()) {

                    Cards card = (Cards) iterator1.next();
                    titleInCard.add(card.getTitle());

                }
            }
        }





  @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            charSequence = charSequence.toString().toUpperCase();
            final List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int k = 0; k < titleInCard.size(); k++)
            {
                String titleData = titleInCard.get(k).toUpperCase();
                if (titleData.contains(charSequence)) {
                    filteredList.add(titleData);
                    Log.i("TAG", "onTextChanged: " + filteredList.size());
                    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(WebLoadActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filteredList);
                    mSearchEditTExt.setAdapter(adapter);
                    mSearchEditTExt.setThreshold(1);


                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Create your own arrayadapter.

Comment: This is a good guide if you want to get started: [Using a custom arrayadapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter)

Answer (score 1):

Custom ArrayAdapter is what you need. Create class and pass it two values.

```
        public class SomeList {
            private String mFirstValue;
            private String mSecondValue;


            public SomeList(String firstvalue, String secondvalue) {
                mFirstValue = firstvalue;
                mSecondValue = secondvalue;
            }    

            public String getFirstValue() {
                return mFirstValue;
            }

            public String getSecondValue() {
                return mSecondValue;
            }
        }
```

Create ArrayList of objects of your class and fill it with objects

```
final ArrayList<Word> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    // fill it up with objects eg:
    earthquakes.add(new SomeList("George Washington", "April 30, 1789 – March 4"));

    SomeCustomAdapter adapter = new SomeCustomAdapter(this, filteredList);
    mSearchEditTExt.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Finally create custom adapter

```
class SomeCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SomeList> {

    SomeCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SomeList> filteredList) {
        super(context, 0, filteredList);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        //initialize view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.custom_list_item, parent, false);
        }
        //get current object from SomeList class
        SomeList currentSomeList = getItem(position);

        //Placeholder for first value
        TextView mFirstTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_one);
        mFirstTextView.setText(String.valueOf(currentSomeList.getFirstValue()));

        //Placeholder for second value
        TextView mSecondTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_two);
        mSecondTextView.setText(currentSomeList.getSecondValue());

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

And don't forget create custom_list_item with two textviews. E.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I used this with a minor modifications and a little adjustment to my own code and worked for me! Thanks!